# Hints? Convergence behaviour.

Tags: convergence-divergence

[image]

I tried many things, including ratio test, root test, comparison test, cauchy criterion, rewriting w.r.t e^n and doing all these tests again, but no luck in any direction. Any hints?

It seems most likely that I missed out on rewriting this stuff to resemble something that can be compared.

Comment: The root test definitely works here.

Answer (score 1):

Root test should work since
$$\sqrt[n]{\frac{n^{\ln n}}{(\ln n)^n}} = \frac{n^{\frac{\ln n}{n}}}{\ln n} = \frac{e^\frac{\ln^2n}{n}}{\ln n}$$

Comment: This is simpler than my approach. $+1$. My approach has the benefit of giving a rate of convergence, so it isn’t useless.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Rewrite the summand so that the numerator and denominator are written as exponentials (that is, $n^{\ln n}=\exp(\ln^2(n))$. Now you can combine the numerator’s and denominator’s exponents since they have the same base. You can show the resulting exponent is greater than $n$ (for example), so you can make a comparison to $\sum e^{-n}$.